# mysql event for creating and deleting partition

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to fix and what it wrong in this. Please help me.

```
[[root@xs32v8-brt-mysql01 ~]# cat e5.sql | mysql -vvvv tmp

CREATE EVENT `Rotate_PerformanceData_Partitions`
    ON SCHEDULE 
        EVERY 1 DAY
    DO 
        BEGIN
            DECLARE Old_Partition VARCHAR(45);
            DECLARE New_Partition VARCHAR(45);  
            DECLARE New_Partition_Value VARCHAR(45);    

        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH), 'pn%Y%c') INTO Old_Partition;
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 'pn%Y%c') INTO New_Partition;
        SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')) INTO New_Partition_Value;
        ALTER TABLE PerformanceData DROP PARTITION Old_Partition;
        ALTER TABLE PerformanceData ADD PARTITION (PARTITION New_Partition VALUES LESS THAN(New_Partition_Value));
        ALTER TABLE PerformanceDataLI DROP PARTITION Old_Partition;
        ALTER TABLE PerformanceDataLI ADD PARTITION (PARTITION New_Partition VALUES LESS THAN(New_Partition_Value));
   END
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: Constant, random or timezone-dependent
>   expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed near '));
>             ALTER TABLE PerformanceDataLI DROP PARTITION Old_Partition;
>                 A' at line 14 Bye [root@xs32v8-brt-mysql01 ~]#

Comment: I give you an upvote because I think your question is quite high-level and interesting. But note: although high level English is not expected here, following a [minimal set of the spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is gladly welcomed.

Comment: Thanks Peter and I my very sorry for my poor communication.